# Issue when I try passing parameters to find command?

Tags: shell, find, quoting

Parameter:

```
export exc_lst='! -path  "/var/app/s2/pnl/incoming/recondata/*.*"';
```

When I try using the below find commands:

```
find $FILE_DIR -name "*.*"  "${exc_lst}" -type f -mtime +20 -user sh79790 -ls
```

it throws an error :Missing conjunction

```
find $FILE_DIR -name "*.*"  ${exc_lst} -type f -mtime +20 -user sh79790 -ls
```

it doesn't exclude the mentioned path.

When I pass the value directly, it works fine i.e.

```
find $FILE_DIR -name "*.*" ! -path  "/var/app/s2/pnl/incoming/recondata/*.*" -type f -mtime +20 -user sh79790 -ls
```

I need to resolve the variable which will have all the files to exclude from find command.

Answer (score 3):

You have quoting problems.

Tip: stick an `echo` in front of the command line to see what it's actually expanding to. Even more explicit, for showing exactly where each argument is separated, stick `python -c "import sys; print sys.argv[1:]"` in front of the command line.

```
python -c "import sys; print sys.argv[1:]" \
    find $FILE_DIR -name "*.*"  "${exc_lst}" -type f -mtime +20 -user sh79790 -ls
```

outputs:

```
['find', '-name', '*.*', '! -path  "/var/app/s2/pnl/incoming/recondata/*.*"', '-type', 'f', '-mtime', '+20', '-user', 'sh79790', '-ls']
```

As you can see, `! -path  "/var/app/s2/pnl/incoming/recondata/*.*"` is provided as a single big argument with spaces and quotes inside it. That's what you ask for when you quote `${exc_lst}"`: don't expand. `find` does not recognize this. It needs `!`, `-path`, and the path all as separate arguments.

Now:

```
echo find $FILE_DIR -name "*.*"  ${exc_lst} -type f -mtime +20 -user sh79790 -ls
```

outputs:

```
find -name *.* ! -path "/var/app/s2/pnl/incoming/recondata/*.*" -type f -mtime +20 -user sh79790 -ls
```

As you can see, there are literal double quote characters around the pathname. It's going to exclude a path that literally contains those quotes, which won't occur.

Try defining `exc_lst` without those quotes:

```
export exc_lst='! -path  /var/app/s2/pnl/incoming/recondata/*.*'
```

and then using your second form:

```
find $FILE_DIR -name "*.*"  ${exc_lst} -type f -mtime +20 -user sh79790 -ls
```

Luckily, the path to exclude does not contain any spaces. If it did, you would have a much harder time of accomplishing this.

Note: All my sample output is missing the first argument to `find` because `$FILE_DIR` is not defined in my shell (you haven't specified its value) but if it were defined it would be there.

Comment: Thanks, but when i try to export the parameter without the single quotes and use it in the find command ,the * is expanded to actual name and find command fails:
echo find /var/app/s2/pnl/incoming/ -name *.* ! -path /var/app/s2/pnl/incoming/recondata/OASYSFX_FOR_GENESISFX_orig.20150731 /var/app/s2/pnl/incoming/recondata/OASYS_FOR_GENESIS_orig.20150731.gz /var/app/s2/pnl/incoming/recondata/PASS2_POSTPROC.......

Comment: @surajhebbar indeed — that's why you need the single quotes or backslashes around the asterisks or something

Comment: Relying on the unquoted `$exc_lst` won't work if `/var/app/s2/pnl/incoming/recondata/*.*` matches a file (which is likely if the exclusion is useful).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot at the same time define `exec_lst` the way you did and prevent file name expansion by the shell.

`-path` and it's argument must be in separate arguments

So I recommend to use `-path* directly in the command line and only put the path into the shell variable.

Another way may be to omit the " around $[exed_lst] and add one or two backslashes before each star in the variable assignment.